# How to update showDialog & AlertDialog via Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-provider

Example: i opened the dialog window, and click the button. Text on the button, have to change, after my click on the button in the dialog window. How can i do it via only [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)?

[Example the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x35xn.png)

**code main**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: TheMyModel()),
      ...
      ...
      ...
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Main Page',
    theme: ThemeData(
      ...
      ...
      ...
    ),
    initialRoute: initRoute,
    routes: {
      ...
      ...
      ...
    },
  ),
);
```

}

**code showDialog:**

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (dialog) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            // the text
            child: Text(model.myText1),
            onPressed: () {
              // will update the text
              model.updateText();
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: I know the [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) and i can use it, but i want to use only Provider. Is it possible?

Comment: Check the link! I think you will get your answer from here.... https://github.com/nyakaz73/dialogStateManagementFlutter

Comment: @Babul 
Unfortunately this example did not help me

Answer (score 0):

Change the value through context.read... and rebuild the ui through watch.

```
class ProviderTest extends ChangeNotifier{
  String _text = '';
  String get text => _text;

  setText(String str){
   _text = str;
   notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Alert Dialog

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (dialog) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            // the text
            child: Text('${context.watch<ProviderTest>().text}'),
            onPressed: () {
              // will update the text
              //str is your text you want to change
              context.read<ProviderTest>().setText(str);
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: Jungwon, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The dialog window is not refreshed after clicking the button.

Comment: How does your update function work? Please at least share the executable source.

Comment: Jungwon, i don't care how it is updated, it is important for me that it works. My update function is the same as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here to update dialog value according to value changed in your controller without closing dialog using `Provider` package. You must use `ChangeNotifierProvider` widget.

Sample code

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (context) {


    final _controller = Provider.of<SessionController>(context, listen: true);


    return Dialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [


            /// ChangeNotifierProvider used for update value
            ChangeNotifierProvider<SessionController>.value(
              value: _controller,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: AppText(
                    text: "Your session starts in ${_controller.sessionStartsIn} Secs",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```